# Regex does not match when run in a script, but matches when run in console?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code, that looks if some values match a regex

```
$ValueRegex = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "year" = "^(201[0-9]|2020)$"
    "color" = "^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{6})$"
    "ID" = "^\d{9}$"
}
<#
    $SplitUp looks like this, each row is an object:
    year:2019
    ID:599245247
    color:#ffffff
#>
foreach ($b in $SplitUp) {
    $x = $b -split ":"
    $CompareVal = $ValueRegex | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $x[0]
    if ($CompareVal) {
        $Compare = $x[1]
        if ($Compare -match $CompareVal) { 
            $MatchCount++
        } else { 
            #Print Debug Info
            "'{0}' -match '{1}'" -f $Compare, $CompareVal
            $x
            pause
        }
    }
}
```

The weird thing that happens is, that sometimes it doesn't match even though it should.
As you can see I print a debug info when something does not match, where I output what exactly got compared to each other etc. one output looks like this:

```
'2019' -match '^(201[0-9]|2020)$'
year
2019
```

the thing is - it should match. If I run this `'2019' -match '^(201[0-9]|2020)$'` in a new PowerShell Console window, it says it is `True`. In my Skript it says it's `False`.

What is happening? I tried that in Visual Studio Code and in PowerShell ISE, both the same result

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce.

Comment: have you looked at `Get-Help ConvertFrom-StringData` yet? if you convert the `:` chars to `=`, it will create a hashtable of the values you list.

Comment: Or in PS Core you can use the `-Delimeter` parameter of `ConvertFrom-StringData` and specify `':'` - just learned about this and it's awesome!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sounds interesting. let me try that

Comment: @zett42 I tried to create a reproducible example with some data, and weirdly the same thing that doesn't work with my real data, works in the example. x)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey oddly enough, when working with ConvertFromStringData, it works better. Funny because I don't think the input data for my comparison changed at all. Anyhow, if it works it works, so thank you!

Comment: @Balthazar - kool! you are welcome ... and i am glad to have helped a tad. [*grin*]

Comment: You should use **literal text strings** (single quotes) for your regular expressions (e.g.: `year = '^(201[0-9]|2020)$'`) because otherwise some of the character (as `$`) might interpreted instead.